# Is there a solution to the error "The property 'isEmpty' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a solution to  the error "The property 'isEmpty' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."

My Code

```
new TextFormField(
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.email_outlined,
                                color: Color(0xff979694),
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Email',
                              fillColor: Color(0xff979694),
                              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "GilroyLight",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Color(0xff979694),
                            ),

                            onChanged: (val){
                              setState(() => email = val);
                            },
                          ),
```

I am getting an error in the line

```
validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it will return 'Enter an email' if `val` is null

```dart
() => val?.isEmpty?? true ? 'Enter an email' : null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if that is null or not

```
 validator: (val) {  
    if(val != null){
        val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition for when it's null

```
validator: (val) => (val==null || val.isEmpty) ? 'Enter an email' : null,
```